# Start intent after Reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, reboot

I have a GPS Service that gets GPS position every 60 seconds. It's working okay, but it doesn't do anything after phone reboot. I tried adding this in a `BroadcastReceiver` that is working after reboot but nothing happens. Any help would be great; I just need to load my Intents after reboot.

```
//Start intents after reboot
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class));
        }
```

**GPSActivity.java**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.v("GPS_TRACKER", "Run Start");
            location();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 60000);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<!-- GPS Activity -->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".GPSActivity">  
     <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="com.ni.androidtrack.GPSActivity"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     </intent-filter>  
    </service> 

<!-- Also permission for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Akash, add permission to your Manifest file.

Comment: Yes i have that permission already, i edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest:

```
<service android:exported="false" android:name=".service.YourService" android:enabled="true"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".service.YourBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also add permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

YourBootReceiver:

```
public class YourBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(arg0, YourService.class);
        arg0.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in your manifest file to get notified :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: @RonEskinder I assume that `<uses-permission>` tag is outside `<application>` tag.

Comment: @RonEskinder Your activity is registered as `service` in manifest file. Change `<service>` to `<activity>` in manifest. If that does not solve your problem then please post more code for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, GPSActivity.class));
    }
```